# Reset rabbitmq graphs

Tags: rabbitmq

In the rabbitmq dashboard, there are a set of radio buttons for seeing the history of message rates / queue sizes (like last day, last 8 hrs, last 10 minutes, etc). I tried manually going back further than 24 hours by editing the markup of the radio buttons with a longer timestamp, which unfortunately didn't work. However, it also persisted my attempt to go back 48 hours, so when the page loads it tries to select the "last 48 hours" radio option by default, which obviously doesn't exist and so the page crashes on load:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

The console looks clean, and all the responses in chrome developer tools are 200. Nothing renders in the admin UI anymore, just that error message - how the hell do I recover??? I really need to get the graphs working again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the radio button selection is persisted in your browser's local storage, not on the rabbitmq server, so just clear everything and refresh, it'll all be back to normal!